# Where to place config file created by systemd

Tags: linux, systemd, raspberry-pi, embedded

I have a systemd service running on a Raspberry Pi that reads the configuration from EEPROM and converts it into the `.env` format. This allows other programs to easily parse the configuration later on.

I assume that the EEPROM variable has to be read and parsed every time the system boots and that the `.env` file needs to be removed every time the system is shut down.

My problem is where to put the `.env` file. I considered using the `/tmp` directory, but it is intended for files to be present only as long as the application is running. Next, I thought of using `/run`, but from what I have read, it is meant for locks and PID. This is also the case for all the variations of `/var/tmp`. Finally, I am thinking of storing it in `/etc/my_app` and then using the `tmpfiles.d` routine to clean it every time the system boots up.

The file serves the purpose for both systemd routines and later for user applications.

Comment: https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s15.html says "This directory contains system information data describing the system since it was booted" which seems perfect for your use case. PID files are one of the more common info there, but not the only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/run` or previously `/var/run` would be the most appropriate location.

Systemd itself follows the model of generating temporary configs in `/run`, specifically under /run/systemd (which would override those in /lib/systemd). For example, your entire `/etc/fstab` is converted to .mount units under `/run/systemd/generator` on every system boot.

(It was actually systemd development that [relocated it to /run](https://lwn.net/Articles/436012/) from /var/run, and it was done specifically to provide a place for all kinds of "runtime data" – *not* just "PIDs and locks"; systemd doesn't even use PID files anyway.)